# Bios Doesn't See HD, But HD Known to be Good

Tags: hard-drive, bios, hardware-failure

I have an [Asus Eee PC 1215B](https://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/Eee_PC_1215B/HelpDesk_Download/), whose hard drive I replace about 8 months ago after the previous one died.  It had a 250GB SATA 3.0 drive which I cloned to a 500GB SATA 6.0 drive.

After 8 months of operation, the drive disappeared.  The BIOS suddenly couldn't see it.  I've taken the drive out and hooked it up to another machine and even ran a full self test on it.  It seems to be in perfect working order.

After returning the drive to the laptop and making sure it was securely connected, it still exhibited the same behavior.  Even more strange, after resetting the bios to factory defaults, it now won't do anything but boot into the bios, and even when I exit the bios it just loops back into it.

I suspect either a failure in the HD controller or more likely that the bios might be corrupt.  If the bios is corrupt, does that indicate the bios chip is going bad, or can I maybe save it by flashing it?

Comment: BIOS isn't going to go "corrupt" randomly that would only happen when its being written to, nor would the chip go "bad", your problem is likely the connector.

Comment: Are you able to try a different bootable hard drive in the problematic machine? Do you still have the original HD?

Comment: Most likely either a controller failure or a motherboard failure. As @PFitz says, test with another bootable drive if possible before trashing the computer.

Answer (score 0):

So I flashed the bios by booting from a sd card in the memory card slot.  It still doesn't see hard drive in the bios, and I've verified that the hard drive is working properly, so my conclusion is that the hard drive controller, or the internal sata connector are bad.  However, ubuntu can be installed on an sd card, so that'll be the solution to keep using the netbook.